# Can Azure Logic App be a workflow engine for a workflow module in a cloud service?

Tags: workflow, paas, azure-logic-apps, workflow-engine

I am creating a web service that contains a workflow module when user will be able to design his own workflow from pre-defined steps, including condition, triggers, and some human workflow tasks.

I don't want to start from scratch in building the **engine**. However, it's OK for me to build the workflow designer / form builder, etc.

The question is, **Is Azure Logic App a good solution for my scenario?**

I've been playing around with it and it seems to me more SaaS than PaaS but for developers who wants to automate some backend tasks rather than a workflow engine.

Comment: Otherwise, open source scheduler and automation tools are available and would be a good base to work on top. [ProActive](http://try.activeeon.com) offers a comprehensive Rest API but other solutions such as JAMS or AcitveBatch may have similar interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use Logic Apps for this, and we have a few customers (like [Plexure](https://youtu.be/en89gyI0ekI) ~28 min mark, and obviously [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com)) - but as you noticed there are some areas to be aware of:

- You can generate a valid workflow definition which will perform reliable/robust workflow executions on behalf of your customers.
- If you need to utilize connectors, there currently is not a way for external users to authenticate with our OAuth-based connectors outside of the Azure Portal due to limitations on redirect URLs -- so some connectors may not be possible
- The designer is currently not hostable outside of Azure, so you would need to have/host your own GUI

Other than that it should work as expected, and your platform can still benefit from the reliable execution, serverless scale/management, and monitoring that Logic Apps brings.  Let me know if that helps or if there are missing pieces that you would need.

Comment: Thanks alot Jeff for the great answer.

Comment: Question please, do you have SDK that contains classes for Conditions, triggers, steps, etc from C# code instead of writing json to build the workflow ?

Comment: It's a non trivial amount of work to turn our declarative definition into a fluent API - not that we won't ever do it but not anytime soon. But potentially tools that will help with this may be in pipeline. Nothing to share today though.